# Import of OSM data into PostgreSQL using osm2pgsql: which formats are supported?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, tilemill, osm2pgsql, mapbox

I followed a tutorial to install a PostgreSQL server on my Mac OS X Mavericks, and to import some OSM data with the osm2pgsql converter (https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/osm-bright-mac-quickstart/).

I used OSM data in the `.osm.pbf` format for the import. That works fine.

Is it possible to use the formats `.osm` and `.osm.bz2` as well? And maybe other formats?
Do I then need to add certain options to the osm2pgsql command, depending on the chosen format?

I intend to import only small amounts of data into the database, mainly for visualizing purposes in TileMill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it can read .gz, .bz2, .pbf and .o5m files directly

Comment: And of course .osm which is just a XML file. See the [osm2pgsql project page](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql) for details.